# Create multiple y axis chart epplus c#

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to have the following multi y-axis chart while exporting to excel:

[image]

I tried some examples from the internet but no luck.
I am using the following code for the this:

```
ExcelChart chart = workSheet.Drawings.AddChart("chtLine", eChartType.LineMarkers);
var serie1 = chart.Series.Add(workSheet.Cells["D2:D7"], workSheet.Cells["A2:A7"]);
var chartType2 = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.ColumnClustered);
var serie2 = chartType2.Series.Add(workSheet.Cells["B2:B7"], workSheet.Cells["A2:A7"]);

chart.SetPosition(0, 0, 8, 0);
chart.SetSize(500, 300);
```

But this code is creating a single y-axis only.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It get resolved.
I simply added the following line of code:

```
chart.UseSecondaryAxis = true;
```